# How to calculate collision with a view frustum

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have calculated the view frustum for a game engine im working on. But now i want to calculate if a box (calculated with 2 Vector3f varibles) is in the view frustum. I have tried lot's of calculations i found online but nothing was appropriate for for what iwould like to achieve.

> Box

The two varibles: `Vector3f objectMin, Vector3f objectMax` are two positions of the object. I would like to calculate the colision of the object using a box calculated with those two Vector3f's.

> View frustum

```
// near plane \\
Vector3f left_bottom_near;
Vector3f right_bottom_near;
Vector3f left_top_near;
Vector3f right_top_near;

// far plane \\
Vector3f left_bottom_far;
Vector3f right_bottom_far;
Vector3f left_top_far;
Vector3f right_top_far;
```

I have all of the above varibles calculated (the view frustum).

If you know how i could calculate a box using those two positions and checking if they are in the view frustum please let me know.

Thanks in advance